Changing the format of an Excel cell changes the formula to a value
I have a VB.NET app that writes output to Excel. I want to apply a numeric format that is based on the cell value, so small numbers show more decimal places than large numbers. The following routine works fine if the cell contains a value, but if the cell contains a formula, the routine converts the formula to its equivalent value. The code also works fine if the same instructions are inline, it only converts the formula to a value if I call the code as a subroutine. The conversion happens when execution returns to the calling routine.
Public Sub Format3Digits(ByRef rge As Excel.Range)
    Dim format As String = ""
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    For r = 1 To rge.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To rge.Columns.Count
            Dim cellValue As Double
            ' Check if the cell contains a numeric value
            If IsNumeric(rge(r, c).Value2) Then
                cellValue = rge(r, c).Value2

                ' Determine the appropriate number format
                Select Case cellValue
                    Case Is >= 100
                        format = "#####"
                    Case Is >= 10
                        format = "##.0"
                    Case Is >= 1
                        format = "#.00"
                    Case Is >= 0.1
                        format = "0.000"
                    Case Is >= 0.01
                        format = "0.0000"
                    Case Else
                        ' No formatting applied
                End Select
                rge(r, c).NumberFormat = format
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

Here's an example of the calling code:
With xlsheet
    .Cells(intDaysRow + 7, 3).formular1c1 = 
        "=R[-1]C*R[-7]C[11]*3600*24/1000000"
    Format3Digits(.Cells(intDaysRow + 7, 3))
End With


Please show the calling code.

OK, I've added it.

You apply the formula and call Format3Digits for a single cell only. May be, you expect the code should affect more cells?

It's intended to work for any number of cells from one or more. In the example call, I'm only asking it to format one cell but other times I give it a larger range. And it does format the cells as intended, there is just the unintended side effect of converting formulas to values.

Add xlsheet.Cells(intDaysRow + 7, 3).Formula to watch with the break when value changes and run the code. You can get known where it changes.

I tried that and it gave the same answer as when I was just watching the cell in Excel. It changes when the code execution leaves the Format3Digits line in the calling routine.

I have no more idea.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Wes 1. I cannot reproduce your issue with the code you have provided. The issue must lie elsewhere in your code. 2. Your code as provided will FAIL  due to this line Dim format As String = "". That is not valid syntax. I'm surprised you did not get an error message, unless you have them suppressed somehow, perhaps in your calling routine?

Thank you, @RonRosenfeld. Are you testing my code as vb.net code? The syntax is valid in vb.net although not in VBA. I think there's something about passing an Excel range as a byref parameter that just doesn't work the way it should.

@wes Oops, you are correct. I tested it in VBA by removing the = "" and it worked fine. I'm afraid I won't be much help with vb.net code.

I would avoid using scripts to apply formatting and use native excel formula  instead. In a new column use this pseudo code if( round down to integer <> original value then text( original value, "#.###") else text( original value, "#"))

Thank you, @spioter, but I don't want to change the value in the cell, I only want to change the displayed format.
